# Futurebuilder infinite loop when results found, snapshot error when no results found

Tags: php, flutter, dart

I'm being inexperienced and new to php, Flutter and Dart for my projects.

Currently fixing the bugs of this code, the print statements loops infinitely when the code runs.

And when no results found based on the search data, it shows an error: Expected a value of type 'List, but got one of the type String', but the results list will stop working.

If I remove the setstate, the results in the list will not refresh.

```
class Visitor {
  final int id; 
  final String? photourl;
  final String name, email, password, address, phone;
  final DateTime birthdate;
 
  Visitor({required this.id, required this.name, required this.email, 
  required this.password, required this.address, required this.phone, 
  required this.birthdate, this.photourl,});
 
  factory Visitor.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Visitor(
      id: int.parse(json['id']),
      name: json['name'].toString(),
      email: json['email'].toString(),
      password: json['password'].toString(),
      address: json['address'].toString(),
      phone: json['phone'].toString(),
      birthdate: DateTime.parse(json['birthdate']),
      photourl: json['photourl'].toString(),
    );
  }
}

class _VisitorSearchState extends State<VisitorSearch> {
  late final staffdata;

  final TextEditingController _search = TextEditingController();
  Future<List<Visitor>>? visitorlist;

Future<List<Visitor>> staffSearchvisitor(String query) async {

    var url = Uri.parse(
        "http://localhost/qiu_visit/staff/visitorsearch.php?query=$query");
    var response = await http.post(url); 
       final List<dynamic> data = jsonDecode(response.body);
    var _searchResults = data.map((item) => Visitor.fromJson(item)).toList();
    print("JsonDecode for visitor: $data");
    
setState(() { });
      return _searchResults;
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    staffdata = widget.staffdata!;
    
    super.initState();
  }

  void _performSearch(String query) {
    setState(() {
      visitorlist = staffSearchvisitor(_search.text);
    });
  }
  

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

  final FocusNode _searchFocusNode = FocusNode();
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Container(
      child: TextField(
        focusNode: _searchFocusNode,
        controller: _search,
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          hintText: 'Search visitor name',
          border: OutlineInputBorder(),
          suffixIcon: IconButton(
                    icon: Icon(Icons.search),
                    onPressed: (){
                      final query = _search.text;
                      _performSearch(query);
                      //visitorlist;
                    },
                  ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
    Container(
      child: FutureBuilder<List<Visitor>>(
  future: visitorlist,
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.hasError) {
      print('Error: ${snapshot.error}');
      return Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}');
    }
    else if (!snapshot.hasData) {
      return Text('No data');
    }
    else if (!snapshot.hasData || snapshot.data!.isEmpty) 
    {
      return Text('No results found.');
    }

    else if (snapshot.hasData){
      final items = snapshot.data;
      return 
          ListView.builder(
            itemCount: items?.length,
                  scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  itemBuilder: ((context, index) {
                    return Container(
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: [
                        
                      Column(
                        children: [
                          Column(
                            children: [
                              Row(
                                children: [
                        Text("${items?[index].id}."),
                        Image.network(
                          "http://localhost/qiu_visit/visitor/photo/${items?[index].email}/${items?[index].photourl}"
                        , width: 100, height: 100,
                        errorBuilder:(context, error, stackTrace) {
                          return Text("Image Unavailable");
                        }
                        ),
                        Column(
                        
                        children: [
                        Text("${items?[index].phone}"),
                      ],),
                      ],),
                            ],
                          ),
                          Row(children: [
                        Text("${items?[index].name}"),
                      ],),
                        ],
                      ),
                      
                      //
                    ],),
                    );
                  }
              ),
            );
        
    }
    else{
      return CircularProgressIndicator();
    }
  },
),
    ),
          ],
        ),
      )
    );
  }
}
```

What causes these issues above there?

How to stop the print statements from infinitely looping and how to fix the exception when searching with irrelevant data to show just the empty list?

Comment: `future: staffSearchvisitor(),` NO.  Don't build the future as the future: parameter in FutureBuilder. See the first few paragraphs of the FutureBuilder documentation, or see my video at https://youtu.be/sqE-J8YJnpg

Comment: I've read the documentation for FutureBuilder, and I've modified the code above there by stopping the infinite loop.

But there are a few problems yet.
1. When I proceed to the list in the beginning, there's no entire data shown within the data with empty keyword unless I click on the search button unlike before.

2. When I search with irrelevant keywords, I got this exception.
Error: Expected a value of type 'List<dynamic>', but got one of type 'String'

And there's no indicating the cause of the line of code.